# Blue Yeti microphone doesn't work on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, 21.10

I asked similar question concerning 21.04 but that release is no longer suported so my question was closed as off-topic. I upgraded to 21.10 so I'll try my luck again.

The problem with Blue Yeti persists. It doesn't work on Skype and it doesn't work on Google Meet. When I boot up my PC and launch Skype I get an error saying 'There is a problem with your audio device' and people cannot hear me. In System settings and Skype settings Blue Yeti is selected. When I disconnect the cable from my microphone and plug it back in, it works.
I tried the same solution while on Google Meet but it didn't work at all.
[image]

Comment: Don't forget warning notices for Ubuntu 21.10's approaching it's *end-of-life* have already gone out - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/ so consider or plan the very soon upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.   (*You don't need notices if you think about it; 21.10 = 2021.October + 9 months tells you the EOL, just as it did with 21.04 or 2021-April release, but once on 22.04 LTS you can stay on that for years!*)

Comment: @user535733 Very funny...If you read my question carefuly you will know.